# How to view a raster in CartoDB?

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, carto

What is the easiest way to view a raster in CartoDB?

From the list of formats that you can upload into CartoDB, I noticed that .tif is available, so I've tried adding a GeoTIFF, but it says that there is no geometry and it doesn't display anything.

Comment: Yes, rasters have not been completed in CartoDB. You can import the data and interact with it via SQL. There is no way to visualize it on your maps **yet**. We have been tinkering with how to do it for some time now, but have an active experimental branch now. There are some things that will need to change about the design before we deploy anything supported, so I would still count it as a few months away.

Comment: You say that you can import the data and interact with it via SQL... can you visualize it that way?

Comment: @andrewxhill Andrew - has there been any progress on rasters?

Answer (score 2):

This example may help you http://bl.ocks.org/jorgeas80/4c7169c9b6356858f3cc. Using [Maps API](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/maps-api.html)